# Loading other images into tensorflow, apart from MNIST

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, skflow

Iam interested in applying a convolutional neural networks using tensorflow. However, the only tutorial i have seen is loading the MNIST dataset. I have tried replicating the procedure done there and reading chunks of tutorials around the interwebs but it's not working. Here is my code so far

```
import tensorflow as tf
import os
import numpy as np

filename = os.getcwd() + '/sample_images/*.png'
filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(tf.train.match_filenames_once(filename))

image_reader = tf.WholeFileReader()

_, image_file = image_reader.read(filename_queue)


image = tf.image.decode_png(image_file, 3)
image = tf.image.rgb_to_grayscale(image, name=None)
image = tf.image.resize_images(image, 28, 28, method=0, align_corners=False)

data = []
with tf.Session() as sess:
    tf.initialize_all_variables().run()

    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)

    image_tensor = sess.run([image])
    data.append(image_tensor)
    #print(image_tensor)
    coord.request_stop()
    coord.join(threads)

xx = np.asarray(data)
print xx[0].shape
```

Basically, i want to do the following:-
 - Load images in from the folder with their names

- resize each image to 28*28
- change it to grey scale
- turn it into a tensor and add it to a training set
- create it's target(from it's label and add it to a numpy array)
- repeat for all images in the folder

when i am done, pass the dataset and target to a tensorflow RNN

All help will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the [generic_input_producer](https://github.com/TensorVision/TensorVision/blob/master/examples/inputs/generic_input.py) of [TensorVision](https://github.com/TensorVision/TensorVision). The input function takes a list of images and returns a tensor representing a batch of images. Preprocessing, including resize is also done in there.